# When setting up Vue 3 + Quasar with a Firebase config.ts file I get this eslint error: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework, typescript-eslint

I have just setup a fresh Vue 3 [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) project using the Quasar CLI.

And I have created a new `src/firebase/config.ts` file to store my firebase configuration, it looks like this:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
import { getFirestore, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'REDACTED',
  authDomain: 'REDACTED',
  projectId: 'REDACTED',
  storageBucket: 'REDACTED',
  messagingSenderId: 'REDACTED',
  appId: 'REDACTED',
  measurementId: 'REDACTED',
};

// Initialize Firebase
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//Export modules
export const db = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
export const store = getStorage(firebaseApp);
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const timestamp = serverTimestamp();
```

But the `const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);` line is throwing an eslint error of `Unsafe assignment of an 'any' value. eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`.

Here is the `.eslintrc.js` file made by Quasar CLI during project creation:

```
const { resolve } = require('path');
module.exports = {
  // https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy
  // This option interrupts the configuration hierarchy at this file
  // Remove this if you have an higher level ESLint config file (it usually happens into a monorepos)
  root: true,

  // https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#how-to-use-custom-parser
  // Must use parserOptions instead of "parser" to allow vue-eslint-parser to keep working
  // `parser: 'vue-eslint-parser'` is already included with any 'plugin:vue/**' config and should be omitted
  parserOptions: {
    // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/parser#configuration
    // https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin#eslint
    // Needed to make the parser take into account 'vue' files
    extraFileExtensions: ['.vue'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    project: resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    ecmaVersion: 2018, // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
    sourceType: 'module' // Allows for the use of imports
  },

  env: {
    browser: true
  },

  // Rules order is important, please avoid shuffling them
  extends: [
    // Base ESLint recommended rules
    // 'eslint:recommended',

    // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin#usage
    // ESLint typescript rules
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    // consider disabling this class of rules if linting takes too long
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',

    // Uncomment any of the lines below to choose desired strictness,
    // but leave only one uncommented!
    // See https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/#available-rules
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential', // Priority A: Essential (Error Prevention)
    // 'plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended', // Priority B: Strongly Recommended (Improving Readability)
    // 'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended', // Priority C: Recommended (Minimizing Arbitrary Choices and Cognitive Overhead)

    // https://github.com/prettier/eslint-config-prettier#installation
    // usage with Prettier, provided by 'eslint-config-prettier'.
    'prettier'
  ],

  plugins: [
    // required to apply rules which need type information
    '@typescript-eslint',

    // https://eslint.vuejs.org/user-guide/#why-doesn-t-it-work-on-vue-file
    // required to lint *.vue files
    'vue',

    // https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/389#issuecomment-509292674
    // Prettier has not been included as plugin to avoid performance impact
    // add it as an extension for your IDE
  ],

  globals: {
    ga: 'readonly', // Google Analytics
    cordova: 'readonly',
    __statics: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_SERVER__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_CLIENT__: 'readonly',
    __QUASAR_SSR_PWA__: 'readonly',
    process: 'readonly',
    Capacitor: 'readonly',
    chrome: 'readonly',
    defineProps: 'readonly',
    defineEmits: 'readonly',
    defineExpose: 'readonly',
    withDefaults: 'readonly'
  },

  // add your custom rules here
  rules: {
    'prefer-promise-reject-errors': 'off',

    // TypeScript
    quotes: ['warn', 'single', { avoidEscape: true }],
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',

    // allow debugger during development only
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why I am seeing this error.

When creating projects using the Vue CLI instead of the Quasar CLI I do not get the same error.

Since the Vue CLI creates a different type of `.eslintrc.js` compared to the Quasar CLI `.eslintrc.js` file I assume the problem is the configuration chosen by the Quasar CLI.

Here is a copy of the `.eslintrc.js` file from the projects created using the Vue CLI.

Maybe to fix the errors some parts of this version could be safely merged into the `.eslintrc.js` file created by Quasar?

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "@vue/typescript/recommended",
    "@vue/prettier",
    "@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020,
  },
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
  },
  globals: {
    defineProps: 'readonly',
    defineEmits: 'readonly',
    defineExpose: 'readonly',
    withDefaults: 'readonly'
  }
};
```

Comment: More of a Typescript error no?

Comment: @kissu yes well it's a typescript error produced by eslint, I think?

Comment: Why you have commented this line // 'eslint:recommended', while generating through in Quasar CLI as it exists in Vue CLI @TinyTiger

Comment: @FaisalNadeem I don't remember doing that, maybe it was done automatically because of my chosen Quasar config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels a bit stupid, but all I had to do was restart my IDE (Visual Studio Code) and the errors went away.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try declaring the type for your config:

```
const firebaseConfig: FirebaseOptions = ...
```

and for your firebase app:

```
const firebaseApp: FirebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

And import those types:

```
import { FirebaseOptions, FirebaseApp, initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
```